# Page to show custom posts and one category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I want to show all my custom posts and category `ID=15` in a page.
I managed to call my custom posts as follows:

```
$type = 'my_custom_posts';
    $args=array(
      'post_type' => $type,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => 5);
```

How do I get to call, besides `my_custom_posts`, category `ID=15`, which is only for normal posts?

Comment: Are you trying to display your custom posts under category ID 15?

Comment: @Nilambar No, I want to display my custom posts and normal posts that are under category 15

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue very easy.

```
$type = array('event','post');
            $args=array(
              'post_type' => $type,
              'category' => '8',
              'post_status' => 'publish',
              'posts_per_page' => 5,
              'caller_get_posts'=> 1);
```

These gets all custom posts 'event' and normal posts from category 8.

Comment: Actually the above code does not work as it takes all posts from every category